# Grid Hover Over... Thing?

Tags: css, xhtml

I really like what History has done with their show pages. Anyone know where I can find resources (or a name so I can google it) like what they have?

Example: http://www.history.com/shows/american-pickers where it says Full Episodes, History Pop Shop, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make the image be `visibility:hidden` (*with css*) so that it maintains its space, and make it `visibility:visible` on hover of the container.

demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hj4gH/2

Comment: And using this method, you'll need to make the big image a background image so the smaller pictures can show over it.  Otherwise, you'll need to make the smaller images `position:absolute;` so they can over a `<img>`

Comment: @JMC, true.. i just thought the issue was being the show/hide of the small ones..

Comment: Maybe it was @Gaby, I was just seeking to give a more complete answer for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the detail popup inside the hover trigger, hide it, and show it in a CSS rule targeting `a.Trigger:hover div.DetailPopup`.